# extJs (Hbox issue)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am developing a portal as in http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html . I have developed the following code that shows a panel with two items.Their height and width is adjusted automatically. But what i want to do is to make them stand in a row.Currently the second item is placed below the first item.I have replaced vbox with hbox but the chart just disappeared. Please help....

Your help is appreciated

```
 Ext.define("Ext.app.ChartPortlet",    {extend:"Ext.panel.Panel",alias:"widget.chartportlet",requires:  ["Ext.data.JsonStore","Ext.chart.theme.Base","Ext.chart.series.Series","Ext.chart.series.Li      ne","Ext.chart.axis.Numeric"],
  generateData:function(){var b=[{name:"x",djia:10000,sp500:1100}],a;for(a=1;a<50;a++)    {b.push({name:"x"+a,sp500:b[a-1].sp500+    ((Math.floor(Math.random()*2)%2)?-1:1)*Math.floor(Math.random()*7),djia:b[a-1].djia+       ((Math.floor(Math.random()*2)%2)?-1:1)*Math.floor(Math.random()*7)})}return b}
   ,initComponent:function()
    {Ext.apply(this,{layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
      align: 'stretch'
    }
    ,width:600,height:300,items:
    [{xtype:"chart",animate:false,shadow:false,store:Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore",
   {fields:["name","sp500","djia"],data:this.generateData()}),legend:            {position:"bottom"},axes:[{type:"Numeric",position:"left",fields:["djia"],
    title:"Dow Jones Average",label:{font:"11px Arial"}},    {type:"Numeric",position:"right",grid:false,fields:["sp500"],title:"S&P 500",label:  {font:"11px Arial"}}],
    series:[{type:"line",lineWidth:1,showMarkers:false,fill:true,axis:    ["left","bottom"],xField:"name",yField:"djia",style:{"stroke-width":1}},       {type:"line",lineWidth:1,showMarkers:false,
     axis:["right","bottom"],xField:"name",yField:"sp500",style:{"stroke-width":1}}]}]


      });this.callParent(arguments)}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you show uses VBox with align stretch that means the items will be placed underneath each other. Align stretch means their width should take 100 percent of parent container so u should not specify the width.
Your current code as posted: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/kcd9g/show/light/ 
I corrected missing ; and width setting, the rest is yours.